# > Как найти сумму элементов от arr[0] до arr[m-1] Например m = 3 А список [1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 8] Тогда надо виводить 4 (1 + 2 + 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
    n, m = map(int,input().split())
    arr = []
    while n != 0:
        arr = arr + input().split()
        n =  n - 1
    arr = arr[1]    
    print(arr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(sum(list(map(int, input('Список: ').split()))[:int(input('m: '))]))
```